# Is limiting the input type in subclasses legitimate (does it give a stronger or the same specification)?

Tags: type-theory, abstract-data-types

Note: I have read a [similar post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/133274/subclass-specification), but my problem seems different from that. Read **my attempts to understand the problem** for why I believe they are different.

## My problem:

I know that (see [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/6/6.005/s16/classes/07-designing-specs/#stronger_vs_weaker_specs) and [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/6/6.005/s16/classes/14-interfaces/#subtypes))

> 1. A subtype of another type should give stronger or the same specifications of the supertype.
> 2. Spec $A$ is stronger than spec $B$ iff the set of implementations that satisfy $A$ is a proper subset of the set of those that satisfy
>    $B$. Therefore, $A$ is stronger than $B$ if either
>
>    - i. $A$ has weaker preconditions than $B$ does, or
>    - ii. $A$ has stronger postconditions than $B$ does.

However, I have encountered a confusing situation in today's programming:

- I have a base class `Essay`, and subclasses of different kinds of essays, say `EssayA` and `EssayB`, that inherit `Essay`.
- To summarise a list of a specific kind of essay, I define the base class `EssaySummariser` that

  - has a virtual method `include(Essay e)` that takes an essay into account for the future summary.

    - `include()`'s precondition: e must all be of a certain type of `Essay`.
    - `include()`'s postcondition: e is included in the summariser and will be used to form the summary.
  - has a virtual method `summarise()` that summarises all included essays.
- Now to implement a summariser for essays of type A, `EssayA`, I define a subclass of `EssaySummariser`, `EssayASummariser`, which overrides the `include()` method:

  - new `include()`'s precondition: e must all be of the type `EssayA`
  - new `include()`'s postcondition: e is included in the summariser and will be used to form.

**It appears that `EssayASummariser`'s spec of `include()` has a stronger precondition than `EssaySummariser`'s. However, it also doesn't seem wrong as a subtype.**

## My attempts to understand the problem

1. I have attempted to treat the new specification as having the same precondition but as having a stronger postcondition: only e's of type A are included. Other types will cause the method to throw.

   - This attempt to interpret it seems wrong, because the new postcondition I imagined violates the original one (original one says any type of e's will be included)
2. I have just read a similar post [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/133274/subclass-specification). Trying to apply the answer to that post, I may imagine that my `EssaySummariser` is not a true ADT, but `EssayASummariser` is.

   - However, the situation in my problem here is different from that in that post. Specifically, my `EssaySummariser` is not a genetic type.
   - More seriously, if the two situations are the same, then I imagine I can convert genetic classes in that problem to non-genetic classes in my problem, and say that some classes cannot be ADT because of such specifications. This does not sound right because I think any specs can be allowed into an ADT.

## My questions

1. Is it legitimate to create subtypes like I did in my problem? In particular, was my attempt 2 correct in applying that post's knowledge to my problem?
2. If it is, how do I map the theories to the reality in the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this, but with the way you have defined `EssayASummarizer`, I don't believe it is a subtype of `EssaySummarizer`.  You have already explained why: the set of implementations that can instantiate `EssayASummarizer` is not a subset of the set of implementations that can instantiate `EssaySummarizer`.  Specifically, an instance of `EssayASummarizer` has an `include()` method that cannot accept an `EssayB`, so it does not qualify as an instance of `EssaySummarizer`.

I suggest you read more about covariance and contravariance, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science).  Your `EssaySummarizer` is like a function `Essay` -> `Output`, and your `EssayASummarizer` is like a function `EssayA` -> `Output`.  The latter function is not a subtype of the former function, due to contravariance of the type of the input to the function.

Comment: Thank you very much. It feels amazing to discover a new topic from a daily problem. From a programming perspective, do you think it is still reasonable to inherit `EssayASummariser` from `EssaySummariser` then? It seems more convenient than Java's way of first creating genetics and second subtyping from instantiations, although Java's way ensures that inheritance always results in subtypes.

Comment: @GuanyumingHe, I don't know what is reasonable.  Sorry.